# Get members of Active Directory Group and check if they are enabled or disabled

Tags: c#, active-directory

What is the fastest way to get a list of all members/users in a given AD group and determine whether or not a user is enabled (or disabled)?

We are potentially talking about 20K users, so I would like to avoid hitting the AD for each individual user.

Comment: I forgot to add that I'm on .NET 4 (alternatively 3.5)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you should check out the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace. Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you can define a domain context and easily find users and/or groups in AD:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find the group in question
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

// if found....
if (group != null)
{
   // iterate over members
   foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);

      // do whatever you need to do to those members
      UserPrincipal theUser = p as UserPrincipal;

      if(theUser != null)
      {
          if(theUser.IsAccountLockedOut()) 
          {
               ...
          }
          else
          {
               ...
          }
      }
   }
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

Comment: Note to anybody using this: this doesn't work with transitive group memberships, i.e. if Group B is a member of Group A, and User C is a member of Group B, User C won't show up in the results.

Comment: Where to specify domain, username and pswd ?

Comment: @Shesha: the `PrincipalContext` has overloaded constructors for that

Comment: @marc_s: This group.GetMembers() will fetch only groups inside the groups. Is there any method to fetch users inside group ?

Comment: @Shesha you want to iterate over the items found by GetMembers() and cast them to UserPrincipals.  `UserPrincipal theUser = p as UserPrincipal;` If the casted variable is null, it's not a user.

Comment: In order for this to work for me I had to change the line `PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);` to `PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "myDomainName");`

Comment: I get an Exception for '(Principal p in group.GetMembers())' I think for all Groups nested in Groups without Members.

Comment: Hello, I am not able to get list of user if logged in user is owner of that particular AD group do we have alternate solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

Please can you try the following code. it use [Search Filter Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get what you want in one LDAP query and recursively. The interest is that the query is done on the server. I'am not sure that it faster than @marc_s solution but it exists, and it works on framework .NET 2.0 (begining W2K3 SP2).

```
string sFromWhere = "LDAP://WM2008R2ENT:389/dc=dom,dc=fr";
DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry(sFromWhere, "dom\\jpb", "test.2011");

/* To find all the users member of groups "Grp1"  :
 * Set the base to the groups container DN; for example root DN (dc=societe,dc=fr) 
 * Set the scope to subtree
 * Use the following filter :
 * (member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=Grp1,OU=MonOu,DC=X)
 * coupled with LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_BIT_AND on userAccountControl with ACCOUNTDISABLE
 */
DirectorySearcher dsLookFor = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
dsLookFor.Filter = "(&(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=MonGrpSec,OU=MonOu,DC=dom,DC=fr)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))";
dsLookFor.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
dsLookFor.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");

SearchResultCollection srcUsers = dsLookFor.FindAll();

/* Just to know if user is present in an other group
 */
foreach (SearchResult srcUser in srcUsers)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0}", srcUser.Path);
}
```