# How I can work with the Active Directory in c# .net 4.5?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryentry, directorysearcher

hi i work with the Active Directory ans work with System.DirectoryServices.

I use DirectoryEntry and DirectorySearcher for this.

My Question is:

Can I use a better/newer way for working with the Active Directory in C# .NET 4.5 ?

If everyone know Helperclasses for active directory then post it please for me.

thanks :)

Comment: I believe that this is already well documented on stack overflow including [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456523/quick-way-to-retrieve-user-information-active-directory) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162897/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-users-from-active-directory). In particular, the PrincipalContext and PrincipalSearcher classes should prove useful.

Comment: Hi Tarasov; I think could assist you in your journey for the answer you are looking for: [SOF Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242226/get-members-of-active-directory-group-and-check-if-they-are-enabled-or-disabled) , or [SF Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90142/Everything-in-Active-Directory-via-Csharp-NET-3-5-.aspx)