# How to get Active Directory users on non domain controller

Tags: c#, active-directory

Using these 2 examples:

1. http://blogs.technet.com/b/brad_rutkowski/archive/2008/04/15/c-getting-members-of-a-group-the-easy-way-with-net-3-5-discussion-groups-nested-recursive-security-groups-etc.aspx

   or
2. [Get members of Active Directory Group and check if they are enabled or disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242226/get-members-of-active-directory-group-and-check-if-they-are-enabled-or-disabled)

I was able to get users from "Domain Users" when running the them on the   Domain controller.

However, I was not able to on member machine that belong to the same domain.

I even logon to the member machine as the Domain Administrator

The errors messages:

Example 1

> Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

Example 2

> Unhandled Exception: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException: The server could not be contacted. --->   System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: The LDAP server is unavailable.

Can somebody please point me to an example or how to fix this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Accounts that are local to a workstation or server are not Active Directory accounts, even if the machine is itself a member of an Active Directory domain.  Active Directory APIs generally use LDAP to connect to a domain controller (DC), which will not work for local accounts since there is no DC involved.

Assuming you are working with local users and groups, you can still use the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` API to get local users and groups.  The `DirectoryContext` class provides a `ContextType` property, which you will set to `Machine` to access local users and groups.

The below code is a simple example that will list all the users on the provided workstation:

```
string workstationName = null; // null --> localhost
PrincipalContext cxt = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, workstationName);
foreach (var u in new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(cxt)).FindAll())
{
    var userPrincipal = u as UserPrincipal;
    Console.WriteLine(u.Name);
}
```